# android bufferReader.readLine() returns rubbish data from C# TCP client occasionally?

Tags: c#, android, sockets, tcp, bufferedreader

i have build a chat application that uses `UDP` and `TCP` sockets, first let me walk you through the mechanism of the app:
from the android device i send a `UDP` packet to a group address which has multiple windows devices listening to it, when the windows device receives the packet, it checks whether it has the same phone number or not so i use the phone number as a unique key to identify the device then if it has the same phone number that I've send the packet with, it will respond with a key says: `"ImReadyNow"` sent through a `TCP` socket and that will make the android device accept the connection and act as a server for that windows device, i had similar problems when i first start making that app, the respond key from the windows device was returned with some rubbish data before and after it and i solved that problem by attaching a key to that massage and i split it after releasing so that old problem that i was facing was when a windows device sends `"Hello"` the android device receives 
`"????Hello"` i solved this one by attaching a key to the first of the massage so
 i'll receives `"????$@!Hello"` then i'll split the received string into two parts and displays the massage only, and that works fine for me till, i notice that sometimes the android device receives rubbish data only and that occurs randomly like if windows device sends "hello" then "hi" then "hello" 
i may receives the first two massages right but the third one will received as `"?????"` 
and as i told you it occurs randomly so does any one know why is this happening?

after debugging `br.readLine()` method does sometimes return `"????"` and this occurs as i said randomly.
here is the code that i'm using:

```
private class ChatClientThread extends Thread {
              @Override
              public void run() {
               /*Socket socket = null;
               DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
               DataInputStream dataInputStream=null;*/
                 // clientSocket=null;


               try {
                   String data=EmpPhoneNumber;


                    DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
                    DatagramSocket socket = channel.socket();
                   socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                   socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(52276));
                   socket.setBroadcast(true);
                   InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(
                           "224.0.1.2");
                   System.out.println("HELLO");
                   System.out.println(data);
                   DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(),
                       group, 52276);
                   serverSocket=new ServerSocket();
                   serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                    serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(4125));
                  int i=0;
                   while(i<=30){
                   Thread.sleep(200);
                   socket.send(packet);
                   i++;
                   }

                   while(true){

                       clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                       BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                       strAcceptConnection= br.readLine();
                       System.out.println(strAcceptConnection);
                       if(!strAcceptConnection.contains("$@!")){
                           updateTextView("<font color=\"#0000A0\"> <b>"+empNameChat+": </b></font>"+"Error in recieving msg");
                       }else{
                       String parts[]=  strAcceptConnection.split("[$@!]+");

                       if(!parts[1].equals("ImReadyNoW")){
                       updateTextView("<font color=\"#0000A0\"> <b>"+empNameChat+": </b></font>"+parts[2]);
                       }}}



               } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                final String eString = e.toString();
                EmpDetails.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                  Toast.makeText(EmpDetails.this, eString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

                });
               } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                final String eString = e.toString();
                EmpDetails.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                  Toast.makeText(EmpDetails.this, eString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

                });
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  finally {






                EmpDetails.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                 @Override
                 public void run() {

                 }

                });
               }

              }


             }
        public void sendMessage(View view) {

            final String msg= et.getText().toString();
            et.setText("");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Socket sock= null;
                    try {
                        sock= new Socket(clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), 4125);
                        Log.v("str", "send sock: "+sock.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+sock.isConnected()+Integer.toString(sock.getPort()));
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        Log.v("ERRORTAG", ""+e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.v("ERRORTAG", ""+e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        DataOutputStream out= new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                        if(!msg.equals("")){
                        out.writeUTF("XX$@!"+MainActivity.empIdFromD+"$@!"+msg);
                        out.flush();
                        updateTextView("<font color=\"#800000\"> <b>"+"You"+": </b></font>" + msg);}
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.v("ERRORTAG", ""+e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }

            }).start();
        }
        public void updateTextView(String message) {
            final String msg= message;
            uiHandle.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                    Log.v("TAG", "updating textview");
                    //textView.append(msg+"\n");
                    textView.append(Html.fromHtml(msg));
                    textView.append("\n");
                    Log.v("TAG", "updated textview");
                    ScrollView sc= (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
                    sc.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                }
            });
        }
```

how does the received string look like:
LogCat:
[image]

PS. on the other side the windows device receives all of the massages correctly.

Comment: use a network protocol analyzer (like wireshark) to dump your rubbish message

Comment: what does wireshark show?

Comment: i don't use wireshark! and i don't know how

Comment: so learn it, when creating network apps it is a must have tool

Comment: well, i read about it a little bit and i really don't understand how it could help, like i already know the source of the problem which is readLine() method but how could it help me to solve this problem

Comment: no, readLine() works ok, your data is the source of your problem and using the wireshark will help you to analize the data

Comment: okay, i'll try to use it and hope to find the source of this strange situation.
thank you

Comment: `strAcceptConnection`. Why is not that a local variable of the while loop?

Comment: i use this string to close a count down timer so if it receives ImReadyNow i'll close a countDowntimer and transfer user to the chat interface if it doesn't i'll show network Error massage. hope you get what i'm talking about, im willing to provide more details if it still doesn't make sense to you :)